# Trigger logout custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a custom hooks on my app, here is my code:

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from '../components/context/UserContext'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const useLogout = () => {
    const [, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
    let history = useHistory()
    setUser(null);
    history.push('/login')
}

export default useLogout;
```

This is easy to understand, when I trigger my `useLogout` I want to delete information about my current user and then redirect my user to login page.

So then, I have a Navbar component with a logout button. And I want to my custom hook to fire when I click on my logout button:

```
...
<Logout onClick={useLogout} />
```

When I click, I get an error saying this
[image]

I don't get it because I'm in a React component when I fire the hook, and all my component are functionnal components.

So what is the part I didn't understood about custom hooks here ?

Comment: Custom hooks can be used in the body of functional components, not the part of jsx. Let me add one of the way how you can do it in answers

Answer (score 3):

The useLogout custom hook:

```
const useLogout = () => {
        const [, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
        let history = useHistory()
       
        return () => {
           setUser(null);
           history.push('/login')
        }
        
    }
```

In your Navbar component function body, you can use this custom hook something like this:

```
const logout = useLogout()
```

In yourLogout component:

```
<Logout onClick={logout} />
```

I hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Thanks that is perfect. I just missed the tricky mindset of returning a function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to the react doc its not allowed to call a hooks on eventHandler : https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html